# Getting thread result in another activity for Android

Tags: android, multithreading, image-processing, android-intent, runnable

My Main Activity invokes `ResultActivity` and at the same time invokes a `Runnable` thread. I want that Result activity doesn't wait for some part of result processing (Image) which may be provided later by thread and UI may be updated accordingly.

What I've tried to do is given below.

MainActivity (below method is actually a `callback` from another `thread`):

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Context context) {
    resultImageProcessor = new ResultImageProcessor();
    resImgProThread = new Thread(resultImageProcessor);
}

@Override
public void onBarcodeDetected(final Barcode barcode) {
    resultImageProcessor.setCameraBarcode(mCameraSource,barcode);
    resImgProThread.start();

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ResultActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(BarcodeObject, barcode);
    intent.putExtra(ResultCode, CommonStatusCodes.SUCCESS);
    intent.putExtra(ResImgProcObject, resultImageProcessor);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Result Image Processor:

```
public class ResultImageProcessor implements Serializable, Runnable {

    private ResultActivity resultActivityContext;

    ResultImageProcessor(){
        this.resultActivityContext = null;
    }

    public void setResultActivity(ResultActivity resultActivity) {
        this.resultActivityContext = resultActivity;
    }

    public void setCameraBarcode(CameraSource cameraSource, Barcode barCode){
        mCameraSource = cameraSource;
        barcode = barCode;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        String picPath = ProcessImage(Obj..Attributes);
        //wait until result activity context is not set
        while(resultActivityContext == null){
            try {
                sleep(50);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        resultActivityContext.onImageSaved(picPath);
    }
}
```

Result Activity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //...
    data = getIntent();
    Barcode barcode = data.getParcelableExtra(MainActivity.BarcodeObject);
    ResultImageProcessor resultImageProcessor = data.getParcelableExtra(MainActivity.ResImgProcObject);
    resultImageProcessor.setResultActivity(this);
}

//called from Result image processor
public void onImageSaved(String imagePath){
    ImageView barImgView = findViewById(R.id.barcode_image);
    Bitmap barcodeImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath);
    barImgView.setImageBitmap(barcodeImage);
    barImgView.invalidate();
}
```

With the above code, after invoking `resultImageProcessor.startProcessing()`, result activity is not launched nor runnable's `run()` method keeps busy in while loop. I traced them using logger. When I skip threading and pass image path to activity, everything goes fine beside being slow for activity switching.

Please indicate the problem or suggest better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that the problem was in passing `ResultImageProcessor` object to `ResultActivity` intent as **Parcelable**. I followed a simple path of declaring `resultActivityContext` as static in `ResultImageProcessor`.

```
public class ResultImageProcessor implements Runnable {
    public static ResultActivity resultActivityContext;
    ...
    @Override
    public void run() {
        ...
        resultActivityContext.onImageSaved(picPath);
        resultActivityContext = null;
    }
}
```

and in ResultActivity:

```
ResultImageProcessor.resultActivityContext = this;
```

Answer (score 1):

i think you are missing run in your runnable like this

```
new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                String picPath = ProcessImage(Obj..Attributes);
                //wait until result activity context is not set
                while(resultActivityContext == null){}
                resultActivityContext.onImageSaved(picPath);
            }
        }.run();
```

Comment: I'll try it. Will it halt further execution (intent firing) if I skipped .run() ?

Comment: I tried it, no further execution after calling resultImageProcessor.getBarcodeImage();

Comment: if .run() is missing it won't execute the runnable. i was double checking it just now didin't wanna affirm something i'm not sure of :)

Comment: did you debug onBarcode detected and see if it's called or not?

Comment: Please check I've updated the question. onBarcodeDetected  is surely called, ResultImageProcessor's runnable also gets called but activity isn't launched.

Comment: Master Fathi anyway thanks for pointing out `.run()` this leads me to implement through Thread class. I suspect problem is in object parceling, looks like I didn't implemented parcelable correctly.

Comment: Happy to help :)